# String resource cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, android-resources

I am trying to write a simple earthquake viewer application, in which i am using USGS(US geological survey) feed to show the earthquakes information. i have declared the feed as "quake_feed" under string resources in values/strings.xml. Only error that i am getting in my code is "quake_feed cannot be resolved or is not a field". Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this?

Here is a little snippet of my code:

```
public void refreshEarthquakes() 
    {

        URL url;
        try {
        String quakeFeed = getString(R.string.quake_feed);
```

and this is my strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="app_name">EarthquakeViewer</string>
<string name="quake_feed">
http://earthquake.usgs.gov/eqcenter/catalogs/1day-M2.5.xml
</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Have your tried to Clean your project?

Comment: @Squonk, yes i have  tried it. But, still showing the error.

Comment: Have you imported `android.R` by mistake?

Comment: @Squonk, NO i have not imported android.R.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change from

```
String quakeFeed = getString(R.string.quake_feed);
```

to

```
String quakeFeed = getResources().getString(R.string.quake_feed);
```

UPDATE:

Need to import your R java file like,

```
import yourPackageName.R;
```

Comment: Checked that you have imported R.java properly with your package name?

Comment: Yes, i had added import android.R statement, but still getting the error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51795/discussion-between-jagtar-shergill-and-piyush-gupta)

Comment: How did you import your java file after my answered. Show me that.

Comment: import com.example.earthquake.R;

Comment: Clean your project and run again.

Comment: Now, my R.java is gone after cleaning

Comment: it takes time to load.

Comment: Still, R.java is not generated.

Comment: My file was importing android.R instead of MyLibrary.R. Thanks for the nudge in the right direction!

Answer (score -1):

This can be due to an incorrect string XML file. Try changing the text in the quake_field resouce